# How to refresh the bindingnavigator binding source in c#?

Tags: c#, dataset, bindingsource, tableadapter, bindingnavigator

I have a problem refreshing my `bindingsource` after I change the data on the database from an other form. now when I first run my program all the data is shown in `textboxes` and the `bindingnavigator` has same records as the database. With that being said, I'm trying to add or delete data from database in a form different from the the one which contain the `bindingnavigator`. when I close the other forms and go back to the `bindingnavigator` form, the `dataset` is not updated, it only shows the data from the previous run of the application...

```
this.tblEmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(this.employeePayDatabaseDataSet.tblEmployee);
```

> The `Fill()` method of the `TableAdapter` only works when I run the program, I tried to implement it in other methods but it does not refresh my `dataset`. Even if I close the form and reopen it, knowing that `dataset` loads on `Form_Load()` method.
>
> I tried to make a reload method on a button somehow it sets the
>   `bindingnavigator` `binding source` to `null` but no data are shown !!!

```
private void bindingNavigatorReload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            EmployeePayDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.tblEmployeeTableAdapter NewtblAdapter = new EmployeePayDatabaseDataSetTableAdapters.tblEmployeeTableAdapter();
            EmployeePayDatabaseDataSet NewDataSet = new EmployeePayDatabaseDataSet();
            NewtblAdapter.Fill(NewDataSet.tblEmployee);

        }
```

Hints:

> the `Copy to output Directory` property of the `database` is set to
>   `Copy Always`
>
> the `Copy to output Directory` property of the `dataset` is set to `Do
>   Not Copy`
>
> I'm using `SqlServer 2008` for the database and `visual studio 2010` for the project. the database is a `service-based` database and the model used for the database is `Entity Model`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since nobody can find a solution for this question I decided to do it myself...

First off I had to delete the `data bindings` from all the `controls` from the `window properties` so I can create them programatically. then I had to implement a method that clears all `data bindings` from my `textboxes` and finally do the implementation of the `UpdateBindingNavigator()` method...

before you begin just define these two variables in the namespace;

> ```
> SqlDataAdapter datapter;
> DataSet dset
> ```
>
> `string connection = "your_connection_string";`
>
> ```
> private void ClearBeforeFill()
> {
> txtbox1.DataBindings.Clear();
> txtbox2.DataBindings.Clear();
> txtbox3.DataBindings.Clear();
> txtbox4.DataBindings.Clear();
> }
>
> private void UpdateBindingNavigator()
> {
> ClearBeforeFill();
> datapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblEmployee", connection);
> dset = new DataSet();
> datapter.Fill(dset);
>
> BindingSource1.DataSource = dset.Tables[0];
>
> txtbox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", BindingSource1, "Emp_ID", true));
> txtbox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", BindingSource1, "Emp_Name", true));
> txtbox3.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", BindingSource1, "Emp_Age", true));
> txtbox4.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", BindingSource1, "Emp_Salary", true));
>
> }
> ```

Finaly you can call the method `UpdateBindingNavigator()` from anywhere you want
and it will refresh your data with the new ones !!!